# Continous date availability query in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in my db, which contains following data:

```
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
Id          startDate          availabilityStatus        Hotel_Id
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
1          2016-07-01             available                 2
2          2016-07-02             available                 2
3          2016-07-03             unavailable               2
4          2016-07-04             available                 3
5          2016-07-05             available                 3
6          2016-07-06             available                 3
7          2016-07-07             unavailable               4
8          2016-07-08             available                 4
9          2016-07-09             available                 4
10         2016-07-10             available                 4
```

Now, user wants to see ***all the Hotels which have 3 continuous days availability in July’16***.

I am able to make the query to get the availability, but not sure how to fetch the Continuous date availability.

As per the above data, in July only Hotel Id `3, 4` have the continuous available dates, but as `2` also have the dates available. so how should we remove `2` and show just `3, 4` via MySQL query.

Please advise?

Comment: is it an option to do this in PHP? Then you could get all the data and loop with while through it and filter exactly waht you want. If this is ok I can provide the code for this

Comment: @JRsz yes it is a PHP/MYSQL based web app but doing that in the loop will slow down it, as we have a lot of dates for each Hotel and there are hundreds of hotels, so it will be overhead parsing and checking each date.

Comment: Prashant, may we see your attempt, edited into the question?

Comment: Is there an sqlfiddle?

Comment: @Strawberry no, I have not created sqlfiddle, will create and take care of this in future while posting questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.hotel_id
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN mytable AS t2 
   ON t1.hotel_id = t2.hotel_id AND 
      DATEDIFF(t1.startDate, t2.startDate) = 2 AND
      t1.availabilityStatus = 'available' AND
      t2.availabilityStatus = 'available'
LEFT JOIN mytable AS t3 
   ON t1.hotel_id = t3.hotel_id AND 
      t3.startDate < t2.startDate AND t3.startDate > t1.startDate AND 
      t3.availabilityStatus = 'unavailable'  
WHERE t3.hotel_id IS NULL
```

The query is written in such a way, so that it can easily be adjusted in order to accommodate longer availability periods.

**Edit:**

Here's a solution using variables:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT hotel_id
FROM (
  SELECT hotel_id,
         @seq := IF(@hid = hotel_id, 
                    IF(availabilityStatus = 'available', @seq + 1, 0),
                    IF(@hid := hotel_id, 
                       IF(availabilityStatus = 'available', 1, 0),
                       IF(availabilityStatus = 'available', 1, 0))) AS seq
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @seq := 0, @hid := 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY hotel_id, startDate) AS t
WHERE t.seq >= 3
```

You can test it with your actual data set and tell us how it compares with the first solution.

Comment: can you explain this query a little but for the sake of education? I would like to understand what exactly happens here :)

Comment: Giorgos tried to optimalize the query to the point that it is no longer self-exemplary. It searches for a hotel that is available on day 1 and 3 and is not unavailable (thus is available) on day 2 .

Comment: @JRsz The query returns records having a match 2 days later, start/end dates are available **and** there is **no** unavailable record (`t3.hotel_id IS NULL`) in between `(t3.startDate < t2.startDate AND t3.startDate > t1.startDate`).

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos will this query is hard fixed for 3 days, if I need say 7 days continuous availability, then I need to change from 2 to 6, right?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos looks working, but slow than a normal query, what I can do to improve performance. Result is ok, but speed is slow. Should I apply index on Hotel_id and Status? or on both?

Comment: @Prashant Try to place an index on (`hotel_id, startDate`) and another one on `availabilityStatus`

Comment: @Strawberry sorry don't understand about variables? Do you mean stored procedure way?

Comment: It is an awesome query @GiorgosBetsos.Good job.

Comment: Really nice query.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos one question here, what if we want to get the results between a specified date, say user want to search 2 continue available days between `2016-07-01` to `2016-07-08`. Where we will basically apply the date condition for this and will it be on main table or in the sub-joins?

Comment: @Prashant You have to compare `t1.StartDate >= 2016-07-01` and `t2.StartDate <= 2016-07-08`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Also, in the query it is selecting only the hotel_id, whereas I want to select the whole row which are continuous available, is that possible?

Comment: @Prashant Yes, but this requires a modification of the query.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos could you please guide me with this?

Comment: @Prashant This cannot be done in terms of a comment. You can try posting a new question.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Or maybe edit the same answer if possible?

Comment: @Prashant No, this is not encouraged here in SO. Please try posting a new question, as this is a different requirement.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos one thing here, I have updated all hotel_id's with 2, so that all rows will have 2 as hotel_id. Then I have searched for 4 continuous nights by adding 4 in the query in place of 2. It is returning me 2. Not sure why? Not able to make a sql fiddle, but I can add create/insert statement and query in the question if you want?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that. It works for any number of days. Replace `N` with `3`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.Hotel_Id FROM table A
WHERE 
   A.availabilityStatus = 'available' AND
   N-1 = (
      SELECT count(DISTINCT startDate) FROM table B
      WHERE B.availabilityStatus = 'available' 
        AND A.Hotel_Id = B.Hotel_Id
        AND B.startDate 
              BETWEEN DATE_ADD(A.startDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                  AND DATE_ADD(A.startDate, INTERVAL N-1 DAY) 
   )
```

It works like that: for each available date, count available dates in N-1 next days. If their count is N-1, add hotel_id to results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I didn't get chance to test it as sqlfiddle is not working, but the general idea is to take 2 more instance of table by adding `1` and `2` days to the `start date` respectively.

Then join them based on derived dates and hotel id.

```
select t1.hotelid from
 (select * from Table1 where availabilityStatus='available' ) t1
inner join 
 (select a.*, DATE_ADD(startDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY) as date_plus_one 
    from Table1 where availabilityStatus='available' ) t2
on t1.start_date=t2.date_plus_one and t1.hotelid=t2.hotelid
 inner join 
(select a.*, DATE_ADD(startDate,INTERVAL 2 DAY) as date_plus_two
    from Table1 where availabilityStatus='available' ) t3
on t1.start_date=t3.date_plus_two and t1.hotelid=t3.hotelid
```

Answer (score 0):

This query uses double self-join to find the same hotel available at day a, b and c, split by a day (function ADDDATE).

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Hotel_Id
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b ON a.Hotel_Id=b.Hotel_Id
INNER JOIN table c ON a.Hotel_Id=c.Hotel_Id
WHERE ADDDATE(a.startDate , INTERVAL 1 DAY) = b.startDate
  AND ADDDATE(a.startDate , INTERVAL 2 DAY) = c.startDate
  AND a.availabilityStatus = 'available'
  AND b.availabilityStatus = 'available'
  AND c.availabilityStatus = 'available'
```

Comment: Will this only work for 3 days, what if I need to look for 7 days, do I need to repeat the `ADDDATE` line 7 times?

Comment: Yes, however, then you may get memory issues on large tables. To a certain point, they could be handled if you moved conditions from "WHERE" section to "JOIN ON ... AND ...". But the best solution would be to cache date availability in another table as the edits are made "Hotel_id is availabel from date D for N days" or "available since date1 to date2".

Comment: This approach will work, but unfortunately it's fragile.  What happens if the availability period needs to change to 5 days?  Or 8 days?

Comment: Then any single-query solution would break and only calculating and caching the availability periods after every edit could make the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine...

```
SELECT a.hotel_id FROM `mytable` as a WHERE 
    (select COUNT(id) from mytable as a1 where 
        DATE(a1.startDate)=DATE_ADD(a.startDate,INTERVAL 1 DAY)  and        
        a1.hotel_id=a.hotel_id and 
        a1.availabilityStatus="Available"
    ) >0

    and

    (select COUNT(id) from mytable as a1 where 
        DATE(a1.startDate)=DATE_ADD(a.startDate,INTERVAL -1 DAY) and 
        a1.hotel_id=a.hotel_id and 
        a1.availabilityStatus="Available"
    ) >0

    and

    (select COUNT(id) from mytable as a1 where 
        DATE(a1.startDate)=DATE(a1.startDate) and
        a1.hotel_id=a.hotel_id and 
        a1.availabilityStatus="Available"
    ) >0
```